# I have following code for image provided in the link.After n=2 I cant iterate spaces,please guide me through it

Tags: c

I am new to stackoverflow so please forgive for any mistakes.

```
#include void main() { int i,j,p,n,s; printf("Enter rows:\n"); scanf("%d",&n); if(n==1) { for(i=1;i<=n+2;i++) { for(j=1;j<=i;j++) { printf("* "); } printf("\n"); } } else { for(i=1;i<=3;i++) { for(j=1;j<=i;j++) { printf("* "); } printf("\n"); } for(p=1;p<=n-1;p++) { for(i=1;i<=2;i++) { for(j=3;j<=3;j++) { printf(" "); for(j=1;j<=i+1;j++) { printf("* "); } } printf("\n"); } } } }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you understand the code posted by yourself?

Comment: You should never write a C program in one line, especially if you want someone to help you.

Comment: I tried posting in proper format but it kept posting error that code is not formatted properly thats why I posted in this form in the body.

Comment: You should read [how to post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting.

Comment: `#include void main()` ?

Comment: code must be indented 4 spaces for the stackoverflow to recognize it as code

Comment: regarding: `printf("\n");`  using `printf()` to output a newline is very CPU expensive.  Suggest using: `puts( "" );`

Answer (score 0):

here is how the code should be posted:

With 4 spaces infront of each line of code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{ 
    int i,j,p,n,s; 

    printf("Enter rows:\n"); 
    scanf("%d",&n); 

    if(n==1) 
    { 
        for(i=1;i<=n+2;i++) 
        { 
            for(j=1;j<=i;j++) 
            { 
                printf("* "); 
            } 

            printf("\n"); 
        } 
    } 

    else 
    { 
        for(i=1;i<=3;i++) 
        { 
            for(j=1;j<=i;j++) 
            { 
                printf("* "); 
            } 

            printf("\n"); 
        } 

        for(p=1;p<=n-1;p++)
        { 
            for(i=1;i<=2;i++) 
            { 
                for(j=3;j<=3;j++) 
                { 
                    printf(" "); 

                    for(j=1;j<=i+1;j++) 
                    { 
                        printf("* "); 
                    } 
                } 

                printf("\n"); 
            } 
        } 
    }
}
```

However, when your code (and the above) is run through the compiler, this is the result:

```
gcc -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled.c" 
untitled.c: In function ‘main’:
untitled.c:5:14: warning: unused variable ‘s’ [-Wunused-variable]
  int i,j,p,n,s;
              ^
Compilation finished successfully.
```

You really do not want your code to be producing any warnings, nor any errors.

for ease of readability and understanding:

1. consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.
2. follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*
3. variable names (and parameter names) should indicate `content` or `usage`  (or better, both)
4. insert a reasonable space inside parens, inside brackets, inside braces, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators

Note there are only two valid signatures for the `main()` function.  Both those signatures have a return type of `int`

do NOT post images.  Rather, copy and past the actual text into your question

What do you mean by: *cannot iterate spaces*?

Answer (score 0):

Wow.

It took me a bit of time to actually *understand* what you wish.
Below you can see the indented, commented, and working code. I tried to keep as much of it as I can.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, /* used for "* " when n == 1 (columns),
              used for counting rows for the first block when n != 1*/
        j, /* used for "* " when n != 1 (columns),
              used for counting rows for the first block when n != 1*/
        p, /* used to print all the blocks after n = 1, when n != 1 */
        n, /* input from user; number of blocks to print */
        s; /* unused !!!! */

    printf("Enter rows:\n");

    scanf("%d", &n);

    // WARNING! 'n' can be zero. That would break this whole thing.
    if(n==1) {
        for(i = 1; i <= n + 2; i++) {

            for(j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                printf("* ");
            }

            printf("\n");
        }
    } else {

        // Draw first block; 'i' = rows, 'j' = columns
        // This could be solved with only 'i'...
        for(i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {

            for(j = 1; j <= i; j++) {

                printf("* ");

            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        // Draw the latter blocks
        // Could simpy do "p = 0; p <= n", instead?
        for(p = 1; p <= n-1; p++) {

            // Loop twice, second and 2rd row of the block:
            //
            // * *
            // * * *

            for(i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {

                // Loop once? What?!
                for(j = 3; j <= 3; j++) {

                    // I inserted this here; this solves your problem, "indentation" works fine
                    // I actually make use of 's'! Yiyy!
                    for (s = 1; s <= p; s++) {
                        printf("    ");
                    }

                    // Draw the columns
                    for(j = 1; j <= i + 1; j++) {
                        printf("* ");
                    }

                }

                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I completely agree with [User3629249](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3629249/user3629249)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52676637/7391718), try to follow the rules for readability.
You might also want to try debuggers, be it the Visual Studio Debugger, or gdb. Also, variable names, please!

Have a nice day,
- COlda